# Naming php files

Tags: php, html

Is there any convention for naming php files?
Not talking about php class files, but files that are mostly HTML with some php inside them.
Should it be `my-file-example.php` or `myFileExample.php` or `myfileexample.php`?

Comment: For people who voted this is an opinion-based question - it isn't. OP isn't asking which convention is the best, but rather what standards do exist in the PHP world. It has nothing to do with one's opinion.

Comment: this link gives good tips about this: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html

Comment: From the description of the close reason "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.". 5 out of the 7 answers currently present are giving personal opinions with no reference to standards. The question doesn't mention standards.

Answer (score 6):

[PSR-4 recommends](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) using a directory hierarchy to represent the namespace.

For Object-Oriented programming, the [autoloader](http://php.net/autoload) can simplify code management with relatively little cost overhead at run time. This requires the capability to determine a file path from a class name - hence a linear transform of the latter is a good idea. This might be as simple as `$className . ".php"`

**Update**
I wrote the above 6 years ago - it's a little terse. Some more pointers might be helpful...

- always use a file extension that has special handling in your webserver for your PHP - even if you have rules in your webserver to disallow access based on the path. You don't want your source code leaking all over the interent.
- when I want to differentiate between different types of files which I still want PHP to handle, I use a double extension, e.g. user.include.php, login.view.php
- Here be dragons: http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2016/06/local-file-inclusion-why-everything-you.html
- while all the platforms PHP will run on support mutli-byte character sets and shell meta-chars in filenames, it's still a good idea to stick to A-Z + a-z + 0-9 + [-_.] in file names to ensure compatibility with other things which need to access your files and to avoid accidents.

Answer (score 4):

There are usually 2 conventions you need to take into consideration:

1. used framework
2. PSR-4

In best scenario these 2 are the same. I usually try to avoid cases when a framework tries to force some custom rules.

Either way, the MOST important is to stay consistent throughout the project. Once you pick a convention to follow, stick with it until you start working on a different project. There's nothing worse than different naming conventions in a single project, doesn't matter if we're talking about files, classes, methods or whatever. Be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use underscore separators `my_file_example.php`, CodeIgniter for example use this convention for it's view files.

With dashes, some IDE/Text Editor don't select all the filname by double clicking on it, while with underscore it select, generally, all the file name.

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific for the core php files you have to use your own naming convention, but you can name on the bases of you file work.

Like php file is only display the html then give `my_file_view.php`
if it has database operation then `my_file_db.php`

and so on for the function and for other specification you can use it.

Answer (score -1):

I use **PascalCase** for directory names, PHP class files and class names
and for other things I use **camelCase**.

Answer (score -4):

You'll come across packages using filenames as

```
class.phpmailer.php or
ImapMailbox.php
```

(both containing classes with **ClassName {}**)

(Personally, I use camelCase heavily for fnames, from var-habits i guess. )

Comment: How does this answer the question in any way?

Comment: Modify or delete it then.