# How to Search with id has relation with another column in laravel?

Tags: laravel

The idea is that I have two tables. The first one is called `service` and the second one is called `card`. Between the two tables, there is a relation via the `service_id` column on the `card` table. I want to retrieve all cards which are related to a service with a specific name.

[image]

My wrong code :

```
$data = request()->get('s');
$search = card::where('service_id', 'like', "%{$data}%")
    ->paginate($this->paginateNum);
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to search for cards which are related to a service with a specific name. Is that correct?

Comment: @Namoshek thank you for edit the post , and sorry about that cuz the English not my mother lang :)

Comment: Don't worry, that's why there are comments to ask and clearify. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `whereHas($relation, $callback)`, which lets you search on a related table:

```
$data = request()->get('s');

$search = card::whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($data) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$data}%");
})->paginate($this->paginateNum);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method App\card::service()

Comment: Check the method in your card model you've written in your model to define the relation between card and service, if the functions name is `service` you must pass `service` to the function like this whereHas('service')

Comment: And another bad practice that I've noticed is you haven't used uppercase name for your models,for example you should rename the class card to Card.

Comment: You're welcome my friend and I would appreciate if you hit the green checked button as well. Good luck.

Comment: Where I can get this things that I should write the model's uppercase and also controller . Do U have any links talking about that ? :)

Comment: Here you are
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042304/naming-php-files

Comment: Just read the official documentation of Laravel over at [laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8). The examples should give a good idea about conventions.